# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Does Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express support transactions?

According to the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx subscribers only. But what does that mean?

I would like to start an transaction from an C# application.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. SQL Server and SQL Server Express Edition are essentially identical apart from some restrictions in the latter (e.g. maximum size of a database) - all the basic RDBMS features work exactly the same.

*Transactional replication* has very little to do with the transactions you mean.

Answer (score 1):

That's "transactional replication", not SQL transactions.  Transactional replication is a method *replicating* databases across servers.

Yes, SQL Server Express supports transactions.